# AutoDesk Forge: Model Derivative API. Extract Cobie Data in XML (CobieLite Format)

Tags: xml, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I m looking to extract data from a model using the Model Derivative API. I simply need to be able extract the equivalent COBIe data in an XML / JSON format to process into  data warehouse. I believe there is a CobieLite format which seems to fit the bill but wondered what I would use from the API to generate the data?

Hope that makes sense

Kind Regards,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I don't see CobieLite format listed as a supported export format on https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/supported-translations/

I guess it might be something that you could create based on the information you can extract from the model?
You can just follow the steps outlined here to get the properties and hierarchy info of the model:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/extract-data-from-source-file/

In order to check if those API's will provide all the data you need, you could just upload your file to [A360](https://a360.autodesk.com/viewer/) and check the Properties palette content for each object in the Viewer.